# userform with webview-element doesn't load, program freezes

Tags: vb.net, webview

I'm new to using Visual Studio as well as Visual Basic and still struggle with getting anything to run. The only experience I have is from working with VBA in Excel.

My goal was to create a Userform which links me to frequently used webpages, without using my usually used browser. 
Because I need the form to show a webplayer, which does not support internet explorer in any version, the webbrowser-windows form doesn't suit my needs.
I did however find out that there is a webview-windows form which uses the edge-rendering engine and should load the webplayer correctly.

I have a start-page as a userform with two buttons. Number one opens a second window with a webbrowser-form.
Number two is supposed to upen a window with a webview-form.
While The webbrowser-form is loaded correctly, whenever I press button number 2 the program freezes and no userform is shown.

Any idea what I could try?

Thank you in advance,

Alex

PS: Did not do much of coding, just

```
Public Class Form1 

  Private Sub btnClickThis_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClickThis.Click 
    Form2.Show() 
  End Sub 

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
      Form3.Show() 
  End Sub 

End Class
```

on the first userform, to load the userform 3, which contains the webview.
Userform 3 just has this on it.

```
Public Class Form3

  Private Sub Form3_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
      WebViewCompatible1.Navigate("https://google.de/")
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What is the code for button number 2?

Comment: @Mr Popo 
The full code for the start-page (Form1) is 
`Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnClickThis_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClickThis.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form3.Show()
    End Sub
End Class`
So "btnClickThis" is the actual button number 1 and opens the userform "Form2" with the webbrowser-element.
"Button1" is actually the second button and opens userform "Form3" with the failing webview-element.

Comment: Sorry for the awful layout...

Comment: what have you done for form 2 that you haven't done for form 3, or vice versa. Sometimes its just visual studio that messes things up, try deleting form3 and making it again

Comment: Also, can you call your variables and forms better names than `form2`

Comment: I did not do anything to the forms. This is just supposed to be a "demo" wether the webview element will even work, hence the unchanged names. I created the forms, put the elements - webbrowser or webview - on them, and the code to navigate the element to the google-page that's it.

Comment: Could it have to do something with the .NET Framework? After installing Visual Studio I could only choose Framework 4.6.1 and had to install the version 4.7.2 and the package containing the webview element manually.

Comment: I am having this same issue. I can Test and the form loads. But when I try to deploy the application on another {Test machine} the form with webview just won't load. Have you figured this out?